# Why Mutation onCompleted does not fire if inside Query component?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I want to have a query, which has mutation query for creating items inside, if query does not return any items:

```
    <Query
      query={GET_SEQUENCE} variables={{ id: sequenceId }}>
      {({ loading, error, data: { sequence }, refetch }) => {
        if (loading) return 'Loading...';
        if (error) return `Error: ${error}`;
        return (
          <div>
            {
              sequence.items.length===0
                ? <Mutation
                      mutation={ CREATE_ITEM }
                      onCompleted={ createItemOpts.onCompleted }>
                      {(createItem) => {
                        const update = () => {
                          createItem(
                            {
                             // some options here
                            }
                          )
                        }
                        return (<button onClick={ () => update() }>Create item</button>)
                      }}
                    </Mutation>
                : this.getItemElements(sequence.items)
            }
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </Query>
```

Otherwise the code works, but the onCompleted callback is not fired at all. If I move the mutation component outside of the query, onCompleted is fired.

Why does the wrapping inside of query component prevent the onCompleted function to be fired?

Comment: Where are you getting the `createItemOpts` from?